# Powershell to set DefaultSite's asp limits

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis

I have been trying to build a powershell script to build the app pools and setup the correct limits in IIS to avoid doing it manually, but I cannot figure out how to adjust the Maximum Requesting Entity body limit in the default site's ASP limit properties. I've found some CMD examples to do this:

```
appcmd set config /section:asp /maxRequestEntityAllowed: int
```

but I do not have appcmd and I'd really rather do this exclusively with powershell as I've been able to create and update the other IIS settings using the webadministration module
EX

```
[string]$Account = $cred.UserName
[string]$AccountPW = $cred.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString

If(!(Get-Module WebAdministation))
{
    import-module WebAdministration
}

$iisAppPoolPath = "IIS:\AppPools\TEST"

$oappPool = New-Item $iisAppPoolPath 
$oappPool | Set-ItemProperty -name "enable32BitAppOnWin64" -Value "true"
$oappPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value "v4.0"
$oappPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedPipelineMode" -Value "Classic"
$oappPool | Set-ItemProperty -name "processModel" -value @{userName=$Account;password=$AccountPW;identitytype=3}
```

I've been reading through a bunch of different articles and references but I cannot seem to figure this part out. I can get the default site but I'm not exactly sure which element I need to set to be able to update the value

```
Get-Item 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\'
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

I've also tried this but it doesn't work

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty /system.webserver/asp/limits -name maxRequestEntityAllowed -value "10485760"
```

reference: http://www.zerrouki.com/classic-asp-upload-file-fails-200kb/

Comment: Try `$oappPool | GM -Force` and see if you can find the property you're seeking.

Comment: When I run Get-Item 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\' | GM -Force I do see the Limits property, but the max limits are sub properties and just adding \limits doesn't work. I know I'm calling it wrong but I'm not an IIS guy so I really don't know the proper way to call it

Comment: So then try `(Get-Item 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\').Limits | GM -Force` until you find a property you want to edit.  Not my domain of knowledge, but PS is pretty similar throughout.

Comment: I tried that but the only noteproperties I can see are connectionTimeout, maxBandwidth, maxConnections, maxUrlSegments. I'm sure its nested under something else, which is what I'm struggling to figure out. I'm searching for the maxRequestEntityAllowed and I cant seem to find it anywhere in the default site

Comment: Not really an answer, but `appcmd` is at `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe` or `"${ENV:windir}\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"` in powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It doesn't use the set-item function but it work:

```
cd IIS:\Sites\
set-WebConfigurationProperty -location 'Default Web Site' -filter "system.webServer/asp/limits" -name "maxRequestEntityAllowed" -value 123456789
```

The location param and the " marks made the difference

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work to set all sites:

```
Import-Module "WebAdministration"
Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites | select -expand Name | % { 
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Location $_ -Filter "system.webServer/asp/limits" -Name "maxRequestEntityAllowed" -Value 40000000
}
```